# How to get AAD client profile information in Azure app service with Python

Tags: python, flask, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have a Python/Flask app running on Azure app service with AAD authentication activated. AAD auth manages the whole authentication process and I have zero implementation for authentication in my code.

That was fine until now, but now I need some information about the logged in AAD user, such as username, email, department etc. How can I get these info with Python?

[image: aad]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After login make Ajax get request on {siteurl}/.auth/me. this will give you current logged in user information as claims and along with auth tokens.